# How to string two functions in R with an exposition piping (%$%) operator

Tags: r, piping, magrittr

I want to combine these two functions:

```
`dataframe %$%
  t.test(vector1, vector2, paired = T)
 dataframe %$%
  cohen.d.(vector1, vector2, paired = T)`
```

into something that requires the data.frame only once like this:

```
`dataframe %$%
  t.test(vector1, vector2, paired = T)
  cohen.d.(vector1, vector2, paired = T)`
```

Comment: you can create a user defined function with that, which will accept a dataframe and run those tests. btw, where are you vectors coming from?

Comment: I wanted to steer clear from a function that was purpose specific because I am often running different but complementary analyses. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a list with the two things in it:

```
attitude %$% list(t.test(rating, complaints), cohen.d(rating, complaints))
[[1]]

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  rating and complaints
t = -0.5970993, df = 57.53962, p-value = 0.5527835
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -8.560849235  4.627515902
sample estimates:
  mean of x   mean of y 
64.63333333 66.60000000 


[[2]]

Cohen's d

d estimate: -0.1541703764 (negligible)
95 percent confidence interval:
          inf           sup 
-0.6717788229  0.3634380702
```